# Multiple templates for single custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I am developing a site for a company and I require the ability to have multiple template files for one custom post type. I have three landing pages that all display the same list of services/custom post type posts in a different manner; however, depending on the page the user is on, I want the inner template to change.

For instance, if the user is on the Gallery landing page and they click on the custom post type, I want the single-gallery template to be loaded. If the user is on the Testimonial landing page I want the single-testimonial template to be loaded and so on...

I have searched through WordPress and have found things like template_part and endpoints, but as a new user of WordPress I am in need of a bit more help!

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick solution I would suggest something like this:

When linking you could use:

```
<a href="<php the_permalink();?>?template=gallery"> Gallery Page </a>
```

Then on the single-customposttype.php

```
if($_POST['template'] == 'gallery') {
 get_template_part('single', 'gallery'); // the file for this one is single-gallery.php
}elseif($_POST['template'] == 'other'){
 get_template_part('single', 'other'); // the file for this one is single-other.php
}
```

not the prettiest, but it's quick and easy to roll out.

Comment: Thanks. I have used that and it work great. Out of interest, what would be a better, prettier way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out at which landing page we are (gallery, testimonials, other, ...)
2. Query your posts using `get_template_part()`

For example:

```
if($thispage == 'gallery') {
 get_template_part('single', 'gallery'); // the file for this one is single-gallery.php
}elseif($thispage == 'other'){
 get_template_part('single', 'other'); // the file for this one is single-other.php
}
```

Or like that

```
get_template_part('single', $thispage );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: So I would just use the_permalink(); still, which would direct to a page with the code above, which would then choose the appropriate inner page? Thank you by the way. Been scratching my head for hours to no avail!

Comment: the_permalink()  returns the link to a post/page. I don't know how you define your landing pages (is it multisite or something else), according at which landing page user are you get him a template file. You need to retrieve landing page name and then load template for single post

Comment: What I don't understand is how I can get the page that they are on? How do I put that into the variable $thispage?

Comment: You need to retrieve landing page name and then load template for single post,  I don't know how you define your landing pages

Comment: I have three landing pages, the gallery is page-gallerylanding.php which pulls in the titles from the services custom post type. I have a page-serviceslanding which does the same but the page looks different. I also have a page-testimoniallanding which pulls in the same as gallerylanding but links to a different place

Comment: that's not how it works. you can try it using taxonomies - https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies. Here is the link to taxonomy templating - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61896/how-to-create-a-custom-template-for-a-custom-taxonomy